# Haskell: Parse error: module header, import declaration or top-level declaration expected

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I am saving some commands in a Haskell script in a .hs file while working thru a Haskell textbook. Here's a small example.

```
fst (1,2)
snd (1,2)
```

When I run these commands from the prelude in GHCi, they work fine. When I try to compile the .hs file with these two lines, I get the following:

```
ch4_test.hs:2:1: error:
    Parse error: module header, import declaration
    or top-level declaration expected.
  |
2 | fst (1,2)
  | ^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I've googled this error and can't find any explanation what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I am missing an import?  Perhaps the Data.Tuple import?  Tried that.  A module header?  Tried that.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SteveB The magic words are *top-level declaration*.

Comment: I am confused.  I don't see anything in the Haskell textbook I am using or any references on the internets that I understand.

Comment: @SteveB Which textbook are you using?

Comment: In the mean time, http://haskellbook.com/assets/img/sample.pdf has some information in "*2.2 Interacting with Haskell code*".

Comment: @steveB. Your question has been answered, but the point was the compiler was telling you that you need either a import declaration,a module declaration or some top level declaration. You have none of them: expressions are not top level declaration.

Comment: By the way, when you’re entering things in GHCi, you’re not entering them “in the prelude”—`Prelude` is the standard library module that’s always imported by default, and the GHCi prompt says `Prelude>` because by default it lists all imported modules; if you write `import Data.Maybe` or `:module +Data.Maybe` then it will show `Prelude Data.Maybe>`. You can change this prompt using `:set prompt`—for example, to change it to a lambda without the module list: `:set prompt "λ "`; to move the module list to a separate line: `:set prompt "%s\n> "`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't just put any expression in a hs file.

As the error message says, you need a declaration here. For example:

```
main =
    print (fst (1,2)) >>
    print (snd (1,2))
```

Comment: What did I expect to happen??? I am newbie at Haskell!!!  People on stackoverflow can be just rude.

Comment: @SteveB That was a real question. What *did* you expect to happen?

Comment: I have no expectations.  I thought that statements I enter in prelude can also be included in a .hs Haskell script as is. In the first four chapters of my textbook "Programming in Haskell" by Graham Hutton, it makes no mention (that I can find) about main declaration. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SteveB I mean, you were not expecting the error you're getting, so you must have expected something else to happen.

Comment: I was expecting to see the output from those two statements as I would in the prelude:  1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It appears that I have to wrap all statements in a print ( ) and include >> before a newline if the next line has a statement.  Is there any other way of having a script file that doesn't require that?  I basically want to follow along in the book and save the commands I try in a script file for reference.

Comment: @SteveB Definitions (in the form of (multiple) equations) are introduced in chapter one (Introduction). Chapter 2 ("First steps") introduces ghci and says it can be used to evaluate expressions interactively. Section 2.5 ("Haskell scripts") says that you can put definitions in a `.hs` file and load it into ghci to play around with. Nowhere does it imply you can put expressions in files. Unfortunately that's where my free sample ends, so I don't know where separate compilation is introduced.

Comment: @SteveB You could have just done `valueOne = fst (1,2)` and `valueTwo = snd (1,2)` (or any other names) if all you wanted to do is make the results available in ghci. `main` is only useful to produce a freestanding executable (when the program is started, the contents of `main` is what's executed).

Comment: This answer does come off as a little rude and unforgiving. A user coming from Python could very reasonably expect to just run a file and have it execute.

Comment: @huw Even in Python you can't just put `2 + 2` in a file and have it print `4` when executed, even though that's what happens in the interactive interpreter.

Answer (score 37):

From a newbie to future newbies: The interactive environment `ghci` would lead you to believe that you can punch some expressions into an `.hs` file and run the thing (in a similar fashion to languages like swift and ruby). This is not the case.

Haskell needs an entrypoint called `main`. Quoting:

> Here is a simple program to read and then print a character:
>
> ```
> main :: IO ()
> main =  do c <- getChar
>            putChar c
> ```
>
> The use of the name main is important: main is defined to be the entry point of a Haskell program (similar to the main function in C), and must have an IO type, usually IO ()

Source: https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html

Comment: I'm still coming to terms with why no book, tutorial or any other resource I could find said something simple like "to run a script from command prompt/shell, put the program logic in a main = do ...". Yet this answer right here says it, and now that works. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe most of the haskell code ever written has never been run ;)

Comment: This comment (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197631/haskell-parse-error-module-header-import-declaration-or-top-level-declaration#comment87412581_50197721) from @melpomene is exactly 'more' true.

Answer (score 2):

I am getting this error but the cause appears to be completely different from anything posted here. And the error message is not at all helpful.

Using Cabal version 3.6.2.0 with GHCI 8.10.7 on MacOS High Sierra (10.13)
I'm working from this page: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/haskell/haskell_modules.htm
specifically the "custom modules" section. There you can see the code I copied and pasted.

Besides the tutorial not mentioning I needed to add "other-modules: Custom" to myfirstapp.cabal, and besides the fact that the sample Custom.hs file includes "if x 'rem' 2 == 0" rather than "if x `rem` 2 == 0", here is the problem:

Indentation matters!

This line (inside the quotes) does NOT work "if x `rem` 2 == 0".
This line DOES work " if x `rem` 2 == 0"!

Indenting by one space is the difference between success and failure.

I'm totally new to Haskell. I've programmed extensively in PHP, Javascript, and Applescript, and dabbled in a dozen others, and this is the first time I've seen white space matter. I assume this is commonly known amongst Haskell veterans, but it would certainly be nice if that was included prominently in the documentation.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30292444)